# Given a class name, how to identify where it is loaded from in JBoss AS 5.1.0?

Tags: java, jboss5.x, classloader

I am looking for a JMX kind of option in **JBoss 5.1.0** to find the jar file/location of the jar file/class loader for given a fully qualified class name at run time. This is to understand what class loader configuration are in place across applications in a deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a "JMX kind of option" but maybe this can help you?

Following Java code can be executed to find out where your classes are loaded from:

```
ProtectionDomain protectionDomain = YourClass.class.getProtectionDomain();
File codeLoc = new File(protectionDomain.getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile());
```

See [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/finding-out-where-your-class?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20javalobby/frontpage%20%28Javalobby%20/%20Java%20Zone%29) dzone link.

Comment: Thanks a lot wjans, it's really useful. I am putting this inside a servlet and use it to identify my classes at run time :-)